# Error exporting date/time fields to excel using python

Tags: python

I am exporting two joined tables to excel. One of the tables has three date/time fields that are causing an error when I try to export to excel.  The error code is as follows,

> KeyError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

Below is the python code I am using.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Joining the two excel files
testSurvey = pd.read_excel('C:/Downloads/Survey123/Test_Survey.xlsx')
surveyAttach = pd.read_csv('C:/Downloads/Survey123/survey_attachments.csv')
fileJoin = testSurvey[['ObjectID', 'GlobalID', 'CreationDate' ,'Creator', 'EditDate', 'Editor', 'Name', 'Timestamp', 'x', 'y']].merge(surveyAttach[['ObjectID', 'AttachmentPath']], on = 'ObjectID', how = 'left')


# Creating new file
surveyResults = 'C:/Downloads/Survey123/Results_Join.xlsx'
fileJoin.to_excel(surveyResults, index = False)
```

When I remove the CreationDate, EditDate, and Timestamp fields everything works fine. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact structure of your data, but if your datetime format includes localization, you may need to strip it out. Make sure you synchronize what timezone your excel file is expecting your input, but before you process the fileJoin.to_excel code, you need to add:

```
.tz_localize(None)
```

to your Timestamp field